# Auto scroll down and up in UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an Iphone application ,this contain a UITableview with 8 cells.I am implement an NSMutableArray for store each cells when the cell creation time ,but the tableview load time only provide the displayed cell  store to the array.For avoid this issue i have autoscroll the table view and get the total cell for store to the array with the following code;

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[musicGenre count]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

    }
```

This is working perfectly.But now i want scroll this from bottom to top at the same time(load time) .How to implement this ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why are you considering as issue? why do you want to load all the cells since beginning?

Comment: Thank u for your replay.  I want to add all tabelview cells to NSMutable array since beginning.

Comment: @John What is musicGenre? It Shows me bad access when I used user code I used musicGenre as NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView` you could use something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

  [table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, table.contentSize.height - table.bounds.size.height)
                 animated:NO];  

  [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[musicGenre count]-1 inSection:0]                                                
                   atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                           animated:YES];
}
```

EDIT:

If you want the initial move from top to bottm also animated simply use:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

  [table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, table.contentSize.height - table.bounds.size.height)
                 animated:YES]; 

  [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[musicGenre count]-1 inSection:0]                                                
                   atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                           animated:YES];
}
```

But please consider user experience - is that ammount of animation needed? Because users (especially if they will often use your app) dont like to loose time. Animation is great when it enhances user experience and doesn't cause a delay in workflow.

EDIT2: for scrolling to top (from current position) you can use:

```
 [table setContentOffset:CGPointZero
                animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank u for u r reply. I have implemented this code but this dont give the exact answer.Actually my need is ,first scroll top to bottom and second scroll bottom to top.Is this possible in ViewDidApper? That means similar as follows.    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[musicGenre count]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    }

Comment: I edited my answer but am not sure if i understood you correctly.

Comment: thank u.This code only work for top to bottom scrolling. I want both, means top to bottom and bottom to top.This is for keep the initial position(Top to bottom format). I have implemented  UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
 and UITableViewScrollPositionTop in a same event (viewDidApper)but UITableViewScrollPositionBottom worked fine and UITableViewScrollPositionTop not worked.What is the reson for this?   please replay me?